# WinZip Courier automatically zipping email attachments

Tags: properties, windows-installer, winzip

I am trying to create a pre-configured MSI file for WinZip Courier 6 (latest version) within a CMD script (eventually deploying on SCCM).

The main MSI property to turn off automatic zipping is "AlwaysZipAttachments" which it set to "0".

Now according to [the official WinZip Courier site](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/307/), the "0" value only allows the User to be able to turn the feature off!

So this does not completely turn auto zipping off!

Has anybody came across a solution to turn auto zipping off through with editing/adding registry keys, or adding an MSI property to the MSI Courier file?

I hope this is clear.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

REG_SENDITEM Default=1, auto zipping of attachments is on; off=0

You should use REG_SENDITEM instead...

Comment: Please be more detailed in your answers.